# How to return image without downloading Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have some images in blob storage and I want to get this image through url publica. However when passing the url in the browser the image is downloaded and not opened.

For example:

https://account.blob.core.windows.net/avatares/folder/file.png

Download the image.

I want a way to do the same as amazon S3, when I ask Url she already opens the image in the browser.

example: https://s3.amazonaws.com/account/avatar/pequeno/file.png

Comment: Did you set a content type in Azure Blob Storage? _image/png_